# Clojure string replace on a vector of maps with text

Tags: algorithm, clojure

I want to replace some characters in a vector of maps with a text in it.

This should be a part of a bigger program wich counts all the words in a list of texts.

The input-vector looks like this:

```
[{:text "bla. Bla! Blabla, foo"}
   {:text "hello foo? bla Foo, blabla"}
   {:text "bla blub Foo Bla blub"}]
```

The output should looks like this and should be sorted on the values:

```
{:bla 3 :Bla 2 :blub 2 :foo 2 :Foo 2 ... }
```

But first I want too clean the strings from some characters.

I tried it with map but I don't understand why this code is not working right:

```
(defn clean-texts []
  (map (fn [x] (clojure.string/replace x #"[.,]" "")) (:text texts)))
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
(ns keyword-finder.core
  (:gen-class))

(def texts
  [{:text "bla. Bla! Blabla, foo"}
   {:text "hello foo? bla Foo, blabla"}
   {:text "bla blub Foo Bla blub"}])

(defn clean-texts []
  (map (fn [x] (clojure.string/replace x #"[.,]" "")) (:text texts))
)
```

Comment: When you pose a question about code that does not work, it helps immensely if you take the time to describe what you expect to happen, and what's happening instead.

Comment: Sorry I edited right now

Comment: What results do you get from running `clean-texts` and why are they incorrect?

Comment: I get a empty lazy-seq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is something like this:

```
(defn tokenize [s]
  (-> s
    (.replaceAll "[^a-zA-Z\\s]" "")
    (clojure.string/split #" ")))
```

This removes all non-letters from a string, so when applied to "bla. blah, blah" it will give you "bla blah blah"

```
(defn word-counts [texts]
  (let [tokens
    (->> texts
        (map (comp tokenize :text))
        (apply concat)
        (map keyword))]
   (frequencies tokens)))
```

This function extracts the values for the key :text from your map, applies `tokenize` to all resulting strings, concatenates them into a list of words, converts them into keywords, and finally returns the keyword counts using the built-in function `frequencies`.

```
(word-counts texts)
```

produces {:bla 3, :Bla 2, :Blabla 1, :foo 2, :hello 1, :Foo 2, :blabla 1, :blub 2}

Comment: Yes but the regex should be "[a-zA-z]\\s". But still thank you

Comment: And to make it perfect how can I sort it by values but still returning the same result? Do I have to write a own comparator?

Answer (score 4):

You're applying `map` to the wrong sequence:

```
(:text texts)
```

returns `nil` since `:text` is applied to the whole `texts` list.

What you probably wanted to do was to `map` the inner function on the whole `texts` list, while extracting `:text` for each element:

```
(defn clean-texts []
     (map (fn [x] (clojure.string/replace (:text x) #"[.,]" "")) texts))
```